# Circular motion from rest

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

A particle $P$ is suspended from a fixed point $O$ by a light string of length $a$. When hanging at rest under gravity at $A$ it is given a horizontal velocity $u$. The particle moves freely in a vertical circle and the string slackens when $OP$ makes an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with the upward vertical.

Verify that when the string next become taut, the particle is at $A$.
I have gathered that at the point the string becomes slack, the particle will act as a projectile and that the angle of projection will be 30. Thinking about this intuitively is confusing me. When the particle is travelling towards the left and it has traveled the length of the string, wouldn't it become taut? How then can it be at A?

Comment: Why can't it be at A? A is on the left hand side of the point of release isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the string becomes slack, you have a projectile like you say. Then, you want to solve for the time when $x^2+y^2=a^2$, when the distance of the particle from the origin is equal to the length of the string (i.e. when the string becomes taut again). Clearly t=0 satisfies this equation, but there is also another time that corresponds to the object falling to point A.

Comment: You'd also need to solve for the initial velocity in terms of the length of the string, knowing what you know about the angle at which the string becomes slack